# How to get or know the Data Type of a Ref Object in Java

Tags: java, object, types

I'm currently using `Java 11` and I want to know whats going on here.

```java
 final var variable = new Object() {
      final int x = 10;
 };
```

I can access the `x` by doing this: `variable.x`.

However, I want to know what the *explicit datatype* of this object is. Because if I change `var` to `Object` I'm unable to access the `x` using `variable.x`.

Please, help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's an unmentionable type. You can't explicitly denote it in your program.

Comment: The type of `variable` is the anonymous type that you created on that line. You can't explicitly refer to it, because it's anonymous. If you want to *name* the type then you need to make an explicit (named) inner class.

Comment: Hey @JoachimSauer, this does work too.

```java
public class AClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final var variable = new AClass() {
            final int x = 10;
        };

        System.out.println(variable.x);
    }

}
```

Just wondering because I can't create an inner class with the Same class name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is going on is that you are declaring an *anonymous class* that is a subtype of `Object`.

Clearly, it is a different type to `Object` because it has a field with a value that you are able to print..

> However, I want to know what the explicit datatype of this object is.

The type doesn't have a name that you can use in pure Java<sup>1</sup>.  But it is a distinct class.  Try the following:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         final var variable = new Object() {
               final int x = 10;
         };    
         System.out.println(variable.getClass());
    }
}
```

Compile that and you will see that there are two ".class" files created by the compiler:

```
/tmp$ ls -l
total 60
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  374 Oct 22 23:13 'Test$1.class'
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  525 Oct 22 23:13  Test.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  214 Oct 22 23:12  Test.java
```

Then run it and you get this output:

```
$ java Test
class Test$1
$
```

---

What about this?

```
public class AClass { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final var variable = new AClass() { 
             final int x = 10; 
        }; 
        System.out.println(variable.x); 
    } 
}
```

In this case the internal name of the class will be `AClass$1`.  Try it out and see.

---

> If I change var to `Object` I'm unable to access the `x` using `variable.x`.

That is because `final Object variable = ...` is causing the value of the initializer expression to be *widened* to `Object`, and `Object` doesn't have a field called `a`.

This is the same as if you did this.

```
Object string = new String("hello");
System.out.println(string.length());  // error: `Object` has no `length()` method.
```

---

<sup>1 - You can use reflection to load the anonymous class using its internal name, and then instantiate it, but there is a synthetic constructor parameter that you need to supply.</sup>

Comment: Thanks a mil for this detail answer. What's a good use-case for this very java feature?

Comment: Anonymous classes are frequently used to implement the `Runnable` for a `Thread` or `ExecutorService`, various callbacks for GUI events and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score -2):

Check instance type if so..btw it's batter to leave this on var

Comment: You can check the Instance Type of course. But, you cannot use the instance type as the `Data Type` — which begs the my question.